# Javascript return value from nested function prints undefined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, nested, return

Here i'm trying to return value from bcrypt.compare, nested inside a function.

I want to get the result value (true or false).

Im using coffeescript. Here is the code:

```
comparePasswordWithHash = (pass, hash) ->
  return bcrypt.compare pass, hash, (err, result) ->
    if err
      throw err
    else
      return result

console.log comparePasswordWithHash "bacon", hashedPassword # Should print true/false
```

With this code, value printed is undefined.

Comment: I am willing to bet it is asynchronous....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bcrypt.compare()` is asynchronous. This means that it is not returning anything, but instead calls the callback you pass to it. There is also a sync version of `compare()` --> `bcrypt.compareSync()`.

My coffeescript is a little rusty, but I think you would end up with something like this using the promise:

```
comparePasswordWithHash = (pass, hash) -> bcrypt.compare pass, hash

comparePasswordWithHash "bacon", hashedPassword
.then (response) ->  console.log response
.catch (error) -> console.log error
```

Comment: the sync version works just fine, thank you for the help